# In written English, do you write fractional inequality with a percent-plus or a plus-percent?

Tags: numbers, writing, percentages

In written English, which of the following is the correct way to convey *I have a greater than or equal to ninety percent success rate according to all measures*?

> 1. I have 90%+ success rate across the board.
> 2. I have a 90+% success rate across the board.

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: I should think both are acceptable, but I would prefer the first sentence (90%+).  One could say, "I have a success rate of greater than (*or* more than) 90% according to all measures".

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with the English language, though. It's a question about arranging a collection of mathematical symbols, not the nuts and bolts of the English language.

Comment: I tend to write %+ and read it as "percent or more". This is a personal preference, though.

Comment: how about *>90%*?

Comment: 90+% would seem to be short for (90 - 100)% whereas 90%+ would seem to be short for 90% - 100%. Logically, there seems little to choose between them. What does your research show about which style is more common?

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that symbols can be used (otherwise, we wouldn't see a `%+` or `+%`, and the question is asking to convert the words to symbols:

> I have a ≥ 90% success rate across the board.

If the choice really is *only* between the two sample sentences, exactly as written, it seems to me that it's purely a matter of style. (If forced, I would pick the first sentence. But I wouldn't be following any rule for it.)